# While creating a apache syncope project I am getting "session expires please login again"

Tags: security, open-source

I am working on syncope project. I have followed all the steps given on this page:

http://coheigea.blogspot.in/2013/07/apache-syncope-tutorial-part-i_26.html

At last I am getting this message in place of the login screen.

```
Alert:
Session expired: please login again.
```

What could be wrong with the installation. Any kind of suggestion will be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might others, please check catalina.out log file in `$CATALINA_HOME/logs `

Answer (score 0):

You may get below errors in Apache Syncope if you do not set correct **validation query** in your Tomcat context:

> Session expired: please login again.
>
> Error while contacting Syncope core

For Oracle user below validation query:

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
```

For MySQL or Postgres use the following query:

```
validationQuery="SELECT 1"
```

For example if you use Oracle Express for Syncope internal storage, you should have below **context.xml** file.

```
<Context>
<Manager pathname="" />
<Resource name="jdbc/syncopeMasterDataSource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true" testOnReturn="true"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1 from Dual" validationInterval="30000"
      maxActive="100" minIdle="2" maxWait="10000" initialSize="2"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="20000" removeAbandoned="true" logAbandoned="true"
      suspectTimeout="20000" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="5000" defaultAutoCommit="false"
      jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
      username="syncope" password="syncope" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
      url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
```

**Note that** here username/schema and password both are "syncope" and I am used Oracle XE so my url is "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe".

Answer (score -1):

Try download syncope standalone application on http://syncope.apache.org/downloads.html 
Run the Tomcat inside and access admin  localhost:9080/syncope-console